# How to bind a listview using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, asp.net, ajax

Application used to bind a list view in nav bar from code behind but Im trying to bind it from client side after fetching data using Ajax on page load.

I got the data on client side but not sure how to add items into list view and display. This is the html

```
<nav>
    <asp:ListView ID="lvQueueSections" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <fieldset style="width: 170px; background-color: #c2c2c2; text-align: center;">
                <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 13px; padding-top: 5px;"> <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QueueSection") %>'></asp:Label></span>
                <hr />
                <asp:ListView ID="lvQueueLinks" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Bind("Queues") %>' OnDataBound="lvQueueLinks_DataBound">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnId" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("Id") %>' />
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkQueue" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' PostBackUrl='<%# Bind("Id", "~/Default.aspx?queueId={0}") %>' OnClick="lnkQueue_Click" />
                        <hr />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
            </fieldset>
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</nav>
```

And this is the ajax call Im trying to build list view.

```
     function bindListView() {
         let result;
         try {
             result = $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "Default.aspx/TestMethod",
                 async: true,
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (response) {

                     let queueData = JSON.parse(response.d);


//Data structure trying to bind
/*
                     [
                         {
                             "QueueSection": "Marketing",
                             "Queues": [
                                 {
                                     "QueueSection": {
                                         "Id": 1,
                                         "Name": "Marketing"
                                     },
                                     "Count": 3666,
                                     "Id": 1,
                                     "Name": "Marketing(3666)"
                                 },
                                 {
                                     "QueueSection": {
                                         "Id": 1,
                                         "Name": "Marketing"
                                     },
                                     "Count": 10871,
                                     "Id": 2,
                                     "Name": "Review(10871)"
                                 },
                                 {
                                     "QueueSection": {
                                         "Id": 1,
                                         "Name": "Marketing"
                                     },
                                     "Count": 1473,
                                     "Id": 3,
                                     "Name": "Admin(1473)"
                                 }
                             ]
                         },
                         {
                             "QueueSection": "Audit",
                             "Queues": [
                                 {
                                     "QueueSection": {
                                         "Id": 33,
                                         "Name": "Audit"
                                     },
                                     "Count": 4,
                                     "Id": 90,
                                     "Name": "Audit(4)"
                                 },
                                 {
                                     "QueueSection": {
                                         "Id": 33,
                                         "Name": "Audit"
                                     },
                                     "Count": 0,
                                     "Id": 91,
                                     "Name": "Groups(0)"
                                 }
                             ]
                         },
                         {
                             "QueueSection": "Enrollments",
                             "Queues": [
                                 {
                                     "QueueSection": {
                                         "Id": 41,
                                         "Name": "Enrollments"
                                     },
                                     "Count": 0,
                                     "Id": 92,
                                     "Name": "Enrollments(0)"
                                 }
                             ]
                         }
                     ]

*/


                     for (var val in queueData) {
                         let queu = queueData[val].Queues;

                         for (var val2 in queu) {

                             let queuSecId = queueData[val].Queues[val2].QueueSection.Id;
                             let queuName = queueData[val].Queues[val2].QueueSection.Name;
                             let queuCount = queueData[val].Queues[val2].Count;
                             let RouteActivity = datqueueDataa2[val].Queues[val2].RouteActivity;
                             let queuNId = queueData[val].Queues[val2].Id;
                             let LinkName = queueData[val].Queues[val2].Name;

                             //

                             //How do I add list items with url links, styles etc here 

                             //
                         }
                     }

                 },
                 failure: function (response) {
                     alert(response.d);
                 }
             });

             return result;
         } catch (error) {
             console.error(error);
         }
     }
```

I have added the test data which Im trying to bind into list view. Im using a legacy web application which runs in 4.8 framework and unfortunately I cant use any views to bind it.

Comment: You cannot do that. A `ListView` does not exist on the client side. Either fill it from the backend or just generate the html you need with jquery.